# After a button is pressed for printing, focus on another button

Tags: javascript, asp.net, client-side

I've a button , for printing purpose. I want that after the print button is pressed, the focus goes to another button. But my code is not working.

The **error** I get from firebug is `TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null` . 
The print process is successfully completed but after print, the focus does not go to the "*btn_CR*" button.

How can I make that after the print process, the focus goes onto the "*btn_CR*" button. *Should I need to write server side scripts or this could be handled by javascript? Please help me*.

my aspx code ::

```
<asp:Content ID="AdminContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">
<asp:Panel ID="print_Client_registration" Visible="false" runat="server">
        <div id="printIt">            
            <div style="width: 260px;font-family:Arial,Helvetica, sans-serif;">
                <div style="text-align: center; width: 100%; font-size: 15px;"><b>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblClientId" runat="server" /></b></div>
                <div style="text-align: left; width: 100%; font-size: 13px;"><b>Name:</b>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" /></div>
            </div>
        </div>            
        <asp:Button ID="btn_print" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" Text="Print" OnClientClick="printPage();"/>        
        <div>
            <table class="nostyle">
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="button" id="btn_CR" runat="server" value="Client Register" onclick="window.location.href = 'NewClientRegister.aspx'" /></td>

                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </asp:Panel>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var NextFocusButtonId = <%=btn_CR.ClientID%>;
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/print.js"></script> 
</asp:Content>
```

*printPage() function is in the external "print.js" file*

```
function printPage() {
    var headstr = "<html><head><title></title></head><body>";
    var footstr = "</body>";
    var newstr = document.getElementById("printIt").innerHTML;
    var oldstr = document.body.innerHTML;
    document.body.innerHTML = newstr;
    window.print();
    document.body.innerHTML = oldstr;
    document.getElementById('<%=btn_CR.ClientID%>').focus();
}
```

As suggested I changed the code

```
document.getElementById('<%=btn_CR.ClientID%>').focus();
```

To `document.getElementById('btn_CR').focus();`
but still getting the same error `TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null`.

Comment: are you sure, error is in the second `getElementById`?

Comment: @Backs I am not so good for javascript. I just post what I get from the firebug console. Please will you suggest what could be the solution for the problem. Thank You!

Comment: Guys please give me some solution. Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the inline expression `<%=btn_CR.ClientID%>` in the **`.js`** file. 
Try using

```
document.getElementById('btn_CR').focus();
```

Also, in your `printPage` function you're calling `getElementById(printIt').innerHTML`. There is no element with `ID 'printIt'` so it will return `null`, and `null.innerHTML` will break.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. So what shall I use to get focus on another button?

Comment: I've provided the complete aspx code. Please have a look. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This part of code `<%=btn_CR.ClientID%>` is not transleted inside `print.js` .
 Now because you need to translate it a trick it to make this just before the javascript file, for example you can do this:

```
 <script>
 var NextFocusButtonId = <%=btn_CR.ClientID%>;
 </script> 
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/print.js"></script>
```

and inside your `print.js` you write

```
  document.getElementById(NextFocusButtonId).focus();
```

Comment: Should I use `document.getElementById(NextFocusButtonId).focus();` or `document.getElementById('NextFocusButtonId').focus();`. Please suggest.

Comment: I've provided the HTML of the page. Please have a look at the code. I've made changes as you suggested, but still can not solve the problem. Thank You!!!